# Set zoom level on a new internet explorer child window

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which launches the page and sets the zoom to 175%. I would like to do this for the w3schools link below...e.g. in a child window if anyone knows how. thanks .

IE 8 compatible, dont care about other browsers at the moment.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>olecmdid</title>
<script>
    function zoom(percent) {
      var PROMPT = 1; // 1 PROMPT & 2 DONT PROMPT USER
      var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
      var status = WebBrowser1.QueryStatusWB(63);
      document.getElementById("QueryStatusWB_Result").innerHTML = status;
      WebBrowser1.ExecWB(63,PROMPT,percent,null);
      WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="zoom(175);">
    <form name="form">
    <input type="Button" value="25%" onclick="zoom(25);">
    <input type="Button" value="50%" onclick="zoom(50);">
    <input type="Button" value="100%" onclick="zoom(100);">
    <input type="Button" value="150%" onclick="zoom(150);">
    <input type="Button" value="200%" onclick="zoom(200);">
    </form>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a workable solution for what I needed. So I resize the existing window and then launch a new window and then go back and resize the original window. Might help someone else.

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"> 


<script> 


function openwind() { 


zoom(400); 
var purchaseWin = window.open("test.html", "Google", "width=600, height=600"); 


setTimeout(function(){ 
zoom(100); 
}, 500); 
} 


function zoom(percent) { 
document.getElementById('WebBrowser1').ExecWB(63,2,percent,null); 
} 


</script> 


</head> 
<body> 


<input type="button" value="Open window 400% Zoomed" onclick="openwind()"> 


<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT> 


</body> 
</html>
```